# While loop not stopping Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I've recently started to code using Java, and I've been trying to close this while loop but it doesn't stop even after adding a line that should in theory make it stop.
Here's my code sample, I've translated objects and methods from french to make it easier for you guys to read, so if there's a syntax error, it's 100% due to the translation and not an error in my actual code.
PS: every object you see is instanciated before the code shown.

```
while (player1.money > 0 || player2.money > 0 || player3.money > 0) {
        System.out.println("Turn number: " + turn);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Player : " + player1.name);
        System.out.println("Bank Account : " + player1.money);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        player1.rollDice(player1, table, chanceCard, commuCard);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Player : " + player2.name);
        System.out.println("Bank Account : " + player2.money);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        player2.rollDice(player2, table, chanceCard, commuCard);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Player : " + player3.name);
        System.out.println("Bank Account : " + player3.money);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        player3.rollDice(player3, table, chanceCard, commuCard);
        turn++;
        player1.money=-1000;//Trying to stop the loop
    }
```

Comment: You are using || (or) not && (and), so if player2 or player3 have enough money the loop will continue

Comment: the `while` loop will continue to iterate if one of the three conditions is true.  Setting `player1.money=-1000;` will not automatically stop the loop because one of the other two remaining conditions could be true (we don't know since you have not provided a [mcve])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not stop because you use "or" `||` in your `while` statement. so If one expression at least is `true` then the loop will keep executing. You have to use "and" `&&` instead.

For example:

```
while (player1.money > 0 && player2.money > 0 && player3.money > 0) {
..
```

Or to set all money values that used in your condition  to be less or equles to  `0`

For example:

```
 ...
 player1.money=-1000;
 player2.money=-1000;
 player3.money=-1000;
```

Comment: You have to give me a seconds before doing that  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
player1.money > 0 || player2.money > 0 || player3.money > 0
```

This check returns true if **at least** one of these three conditions is fulfilled. To make your code exit loop when **at least** of players doesn't have enough money, change OR (`||`) operator to AND (`&&`) operator:

```
player1.money > 0 && player2.money > 0 && player3.money > 0
```

This check returns true only if `all` of the particular conditions are fulfilled.